# Error in str.default(tweets_text) : invalid multibyte string 53

Tags: r

I'm able to get 500 tweets in to R however when converting to character with below code i am getting the Error in `str.default(tweets_text)` : **invalid multibyte string 53**

```
tweets_b <-searchTwitter('bahubali',lang="en",n=500,resultType="recent")
tweets_txt <-sapply(tweets_b,function(x) x$getText() ) 
str(tweets_txt)
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What package are you using? Please add the library call

Comment: library(twitteR)
library(RCurl)
library(httk)
library(httpuv)                                                                                    require(tm)
require(wordcloud)                                                                                   tweets_b <-searchTwitter("#bahubali",lang="en",n=500,resultType="recent")
class(tweets_b)
#convert in to text from  list data type 
tweets_txt <-sapply(tweets_b, function(x) x$getText()) 
str(tweets_text)
b_corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(tweets_text))

Comment: can you please check and confirm the error message

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the encoding, check your encoding by using the code

```
Encoding(tweets_txt)
```

If you see any UTF-8 encoding, you can overcome the error by converting the encoding to latin1, by using this code

```
Encoding(tweets_txt) <- "latin1"
```

After this the `str()` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer however I had figured the resolution long time back and implemented successfully.

FYI :

Here is the code i used .

bahubali_text <- sapply(bahubali_tweets, function(x) x$getText())

## removing the non-ASCII  chracters in corpus

b_convert_text <-  sapply(bahubali_text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))

thanks again
cheers